# Features of IDEs for web services

Tags: web-services, ide, soa

What are the service oriented architecture/webservices features available in IDE.

Comment: Which IDE are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of IDE's simply let you enter the URL of a webservice and autogenerate clientside proxies at the click of a button. This means you also get intellisense for the web services - but this will normally be the case even if you generate the service in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Java web services I suggest checking out the Eclipse web tools platform.  http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

There are web services wizards that will generate a service top-down (from a wsdl file) bottom up (from a java bean) and can also generate client proxies from a WSDL.  There is also the "Web Services Explorer" which will let you test a web service without generating a client, and will also let you search and publish to UDDI registries.